# ModalPopup or Dialog Using Google Closure

Tags: javascript, google-closure, google-closure-library

When "add Employee" link is clicked a ppopup must appear with fields to accept user details. I tried many things but ended up opening a new window and not a popup. how to get the following code to work in a popup or a dialog or a ModalPopup

```
function newUsr() {
    var li = new goog.ui.LabelInput('Employee ID');
    li.render(goog.dom.getElement('d'));
    var li1 = new goog.ui.LabelInput('First Name');
    li1.render(goog.dom.getElement('d1'));
    var li2 = new goog.ui.LabelInput('Last Name');
    li2.render(goog.dom.getElement('d2'));
    var li3 = new goog.ui.LabelInput('Email Id');
    li3.render(goog.dom.getElement('d3'));
    var li4 = new goog.ui.LabelInput('Date Of Birth(yyyy-mm-dd)');
    li4.render(goog.dom.getElement('d4'));
    var li5 = new goog.ui.LabelInput('Date Of Joining(yyyy-mm-dd)');
    li5.render(goog.dom.getElement('d5'));
    var li6 = new goog.ui.LabelInput('Phone');
    li6.render(goog.dom.getElement('d6'));
    var fb1 = new goog.ui.Button('Submit', goog.ui.FlatButtonRenderer
            .getInstance());
    fb1.render(goog.dom.getElement('fb1'));
    goog.events.listen(fb1, goog.ui.Component.EventType.ACTION, function(e) {
        alert(" " + li.getValue() + " " + li1.getValue() + " ");
        var request = new goog.net.XhrIo();
        var data = new goog.Uri.QueryData();
        data.set('emp_id', li.getValue());
        data.set('first_name', li1.getValue());
        data.set('last_name', li2.getValue());
        data.set('email', li3.getValue());
        var d1 = new Date(li4.getValue());
        var d2 = new Date(li5.getValue());
        data.set('dob', li4.getValue());
        data.set('doj', li5.getValue());
        data.set('phone', li6.getValue());
        request.send('newUser', 'POST' , data.toString());
    });
}
Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {         

    var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();                                    
    var mm = (this.getMonth()+1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based         
    var dd  = this.getDate().toString();             

    return yyyy + '-' + (mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0]) + '-' + (dd[1]?dd:"0"+dd[0]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Please show us how you create and handle the "add Employee" link, otherwise it's hard to answer the question. If you attached an event listener for the `goog.events.EventType.CLICK` event to the link, and the default behaviour of the link is to open a new window (i.e. it has a `target` property), then you can prevent the default behaviour by using `preventDefault()`. Inside your event handler you could then open a custom dialog, e.g. using `goog.ui.Popup` or `goog.ui.Dialog`.

For example:

```
<a href="someurl" id="add">add employee</a>
```

and you did

```
goog.events.listen(document.getElementById('add'), goog.events.EventType.CLICK, function(e) {e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); var dlg = new goog.ui.Dialog(); ...});
```